# How to find out combination of two columns in Dataframe? when there is multiple columns in dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I have the following dataframe...

```
df1:
playerA   playerB  PlayerC PlayerD
kim         lee      b      f
jackson     kim      d      g
dan         lee      a      d
```

I want to generate a new data frame with all possible combinations of two columns. For example,

```
df_new:
Target   Source  
kim         lee
kim         kim
kim         lee
kim          b     
kim          d
kim          a
kim          f
kim          g
kim          d      
jackson      lee
jackson      kim
jackson      lee
jackson      b
.
.
.
.
lee         kim
lee         jackson
lee          dan
lee          b
lee          d
.
.
.
```

Thus, I tried this code t

```
import itertools
def comb(df1):
    return [df1.loc[:, list(x)].set_axis(['Target','Source'], axis=1)
            for x in itertools.combinations(df1.columns, 2)]
```

However, It only shows combinations between columns in the same row.

Is there any way that I could generate all the possible combination between columns? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way from `itertools` via [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain, permutations, product

df = pd.DataFrame(
         chain.from_iterable(product(df1[col_1], df1[col_2])
                             for col_1, col_2 in permutations(df1.columns, r=2)),
         columns=["Target", "Source"]
)
```

where we first get 2-`permutations` of all columns, then for each pair, form a `product` of their values. After doing this for all permutations, flatten them with `chain.from_iterable` and pass to the dataframe constructor.

I get a 108 x 2 dataframe:

```
      Target Source
0        kim    lee
1        kim    kim
2        kim    lee
3    jackson    lee
4    jackson    kim
..       ...    ...
103        g      d
104        g      a
105        d      b
106        d      d
107        d      a
```

(where *108 = 3*9*4: 3 = rows, 9 = rows * other columns, 4 = total columns*).

Comment: It is really good. Could I ask one more questions? What is "chain"? and "for col_1, col_2 in permutations(df1.columns, r=2)" means?

Comment: @DAEHYUNKIM `chain` is used for flattening a list of lists, you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/9332187). In this case, for example a list like `[[("kim", "lee"), ("kim", "kim")], [("jackson", "lee"), ("jackson", "kim")]]` has 2 lists inside. After `chain`, it becomes `[("kim", "lee"), ("kim", "kim"), ("jackson", "lee"), ("jackson", "kim")]`  (note the disappearing `[, ]` inside, it is a single list of 4 items now).

Comment: @DAEHYUNKIM As for the `permutations`, it takes columns' names and generate 2-permuations of them. It gives `[('playerA', 'playerB'),
 ('playerA', 'PlayerC'),
 ('playerA', 'PlayerD'),
 ('playerB', 'playerA'),
 ('playerB', 'PlayerC'),
 ('playerB', 'PlayerD'),
 ('PlayerC', 'playerA'),
 ('PlayerC', 'playerB'),
 ('PlayerC', 'PlayerD'),
 ('PlayerD', 'playerA'),
 ('PlayerD', 'playerB'),
 ('PlayerD', 'PlayerC')]`. Then with `for col_1, col_2`, we turn a `for` loop and `col_1` and `col_2` are assigned to these pairs in each turn.

Comment: Aydin It really helps me a lot. Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using [`pandas.DataFrame.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html?highlight=melt#pandas.DataFrame.melt) and [`pandas.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.merge)

```
>>> df1
   playerA playerB PlayerC PlayerD
0      kim     lee       b       f
1  jackson     kim       d       g
2      dan     lee       a       d
>>> target = df1.melt(value_name='Source')[['Source']]
>>> df_new = pd.merge(target.rename(columns={'Source':'Target'}), target, how='cross')
>>> df_new
    Target   Source
0      kim      kim
1      kim  jackson
2      kim      dan
3      kim      lee
4      kim      kim
..     ...      ...
139      d        d
140      d        a
141      d        f
142      d        g
143      d        d
```

This approach doesn't consider same indices of `Target` and `Source`, but you can easily drop those rows using simple math as follow:

```
>>> indices_to_drop = [idx * len(target) + idx for idx in range(len(target)]
>>> indices_to_drop
[0, 13, 26, 39, 52, 65, 78, 91, 104, 117, 130, 143]
>>> df_new.drop(indices_to_drop).reset_index(drop=True)
    Target   Source
0      kim  jackson
1      kim      dan
2      kim      lee
3      kim      kim
4      kim      lee
..     ...      ...
127      d        b
128      d        d
129      d        a
130      d        f
131      d        g
```

Comment: number of rows is too  much, i believe (144 > 108).

Comment: Before dropping those indices, this solution also takes product of a column with itself, which is useful i think but may not be what OP wants. After dropping those indices, however, it is somewhere in between.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Target", "Source"])
for col in df1:
    df = pd.concat(
        [
            df,
            pd.DataFrame(
                [
                    {"Target": val1, "Source": val2}
                    for val2 in df1.loc[:, df1.columns.difference([col])].values.flatten()
                    for val1 in df1[col]
                ]
            ),
        ],
    )

df
```

```
    Target  Source
0   kim b
1   jackson b
2   dan b
3   kim f
4   jackson f
... ... ...
22  g   dan
23  d   dan
24  f   lee
25  g   lee
26  d   lee
108 rows × 2 columns
```